# Cleaning up and concatenation of a 2D masked array of strings containing peculiar characters with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Reading a netCDF file, one of the variables is a 2D string array looking like this:

```
[[' ' ' ' ' ' 'B' 'l' 'i' ' ' ' ']
 ['+' -- '\xaa' -- 'F' 'o' 'o' ' ']
 [' ' '1' ']' -- 'B' 'l' 'a' ' ']
 [' ' '\x1a' -- '\x98' -- 'B' 'l' 'o']]
```

**My desired output:**

```
['Bli', 'Foo', 'Bla', 'Blo']
```

Or an array containing those words, or any iterable with the clean words (i.e., with removed spaces, special characters, etc.).

**My trouble:**

My difficulties come from the special characters (where do they come from and how to remove them?), and from the masked values:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.ma.masked_array([(' ', ' ', ' ', 'B', 'l', 'i', ' ', ' ' ),
                        ('+', ' ', '\xaa', ' ', 'F', 'o', 'o', ' '),
                        (' ', '1', ']', ' ', 'B', 'l', 'a', ' '),
                        (' ', '\x1a', ' ', '\x98', ' ', 'B', 'l', 'o' )],
                       mask=[(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                             (0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                             (0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                             (0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0)])

print a
print ''.join(a[0,:]).replace(' ', '')  # this properly produces 'Bli'
print [''.join(i).replace(' ', '') for i in a]
```

The last line produces the following Error:

> TypeError: sequence item 1: expected string, MaskedConstant found

But even with this resolved, I'd end up with those undesired strange characters in my strings...

```
a[a.mask] = ' '
print [''.join(i).replace(' ', '') for i in a]
# ['Bli', '+\xaaFoo', '1]Bla', '\x1a\x98Blo']
```

What would be the best way to homogeneously treat this array in a single operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use this?

```
    import numpy as np

    a = np.ma.masked_array([(' ', ' ', ' ', 'B', 'l', 'i', ' ', ' ' ),
                            ('+', ' ', '\xaa', ' ', 'F', 'o', 'o', ' '),
                            (' ', '1', ']', ' ', 'B', 'l', 'a', ' '),
                            (' ', '\x1a', ' ', '\x98', ' ', 'B', 'l', 'o' )],
                           mask=[(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                                 (0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                                 (0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                                 (0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0)])

    print ''.join(a[0,:]).replace(' ', '')  # this properly produces 'Bli'
    print [''.join(x for x in y if x.isalpha()) for y in [''.join(i).replace(' ', '') for i in a.filled('')]]
```

Comment: Yes! What I needed was `numpy.ma.filled` and `str.isalpha()`, thanks! But actually you can do it in one line then, your `temp` is not needed: `[''.join(e for e in s if e.isalpha()) for s in a.filled('')]`

Comment: Ok. Glad it worked. I removed temp in the edit. But a little bit longer than your statement. :P